# Adding DataGridView1 to Listbox1 VB.net

Tags: vb.net

Quick question or I hope it is quick.

I have a DataGridView1 with 4 Columns and I would like to add everything on the DataGridView1 to the Listbox.

Columns Example

```
Name    Average   Handicap   Paid
John    170       0          20
Alex    180       0          15
Jane    200       0          10
Jim     150       0          20
```

When I click Button1 I would like it to go down the line and add them to the ListBox1

ListBox1 Example

```
John Paid $20
Alex Paid $15
Jane Paid $10
Jim Paid $20
```

I have DataGridView1 set if you click it, it will populate some labels and was hoping there was a way to Select each row one at a time automatically and just pull the Labels.text information as it auto scrolls down the list but did not know how to auto select the list one at a time.

Thank you

Comment: You would loop through the rows of the grid and do the same as you would do to populate the `Label` to get a value that that you then add to the `ListBox`.  The `Label` itself would play no part.  You should have a method that you can pass a grid row and get back the value and then call that method when populating both the `Label` and the `ListBox`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Button1` click event...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim LboxValue As String = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value & " " & DataGridView1.Columns(3).HeaderText & " " & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
        ListBox1.Items.Add(LboxValue)
    Next
End Sub
```

As per your need...

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: I had something similar but the (i) was giving me an error saying it was over limit or something to that affect. I think what i was missing was the
e As System.EventArgs. 
This worked Thank you!!!